# Updating multiple documents with different values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using jquery ui's sortable function ([source](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)) to re-arrange elements. I've built custom callbacks to create an list of those elements. So when i move an element, all elements is given a new position id. It could look like this:

```
[{
    id_of_element_in_database: 12,
    new_position: 0
}, {
    id_of_element_in_database: 16,
    new_position: 1
}, {
    id_of_element_in_database: 14,
    new_position: 2
}]
```

I'm sending this list to my back-end by doing a simple **Ajax post**

```
$.post('/position', { data: list });
```

**Route**

```
router.post('/position', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.data); // This prints the array of objects above.
});
```

**Schema**

```
mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    position: Number,
    ...
});
```

Now I can't figure out how to change the position of all documents effectively. Creating a crappy loop of the array and doing multiple database-requests can't be the best approach.

I've tried that here and this feels so wrong.

```
for (let i in req.body.data) {
    collection.update({ id: req.body.data[i].id }, { position: req.body.data[i].position });
```

There must be something else i can do to achieve this. I've tried google without any luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the **[`bulkWrite`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite)** API to carry out the updates in a better way without multiple requests to the server:

```
var callback = function(err, r){
    console.log(r.matchedCount);
    console.log(r.modifiedCount);
}
// Initialise the bulk operations array
var ops = req.body.data.map(function (item) { 
    return { 
        "updateOne": { 
            "filter": { 
                "id": parseInt(item.id),
                "position": { "$ne": parseInt(item.position) }
            },              
            "update": { "$set": { "position": parseInt(item.position) } } 
        }         
    }    
});

// Get the underlying collection via the native node.js driver collection object
Model.collection.bulkWrite(ops, callback);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and get back to you!

Comment: With this little tweak `parseInt(item.id)`,  `parseInt(item.position)` and removed the `unique` index from the collection this solution worked flawlessly. Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanNielsen No worries, happy to be of help.

Comment: @JonathanNielsen Removing the `unique` index from the collection sounds like more than a tweak: can you let us know why that was necessary, for the record?

Comment: @VinceBowdren I thought "Of course you don't want to have the same position number if you want to sort them" so in my schema I did `{ type: Number, unique: true }`. But when I use the bulk update some of the positions were changed before others so two documents could have the same position number for a sec. I went to the mongo shell and did `db.collection.getIndexes()` to list indexes. I found my unique position index and removed it by doing `db.collection.dropIndex('position_1')`. `position_1` was the name of my index. And after this I also switched to the schema settings that i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it with Node.js:

```
var forEach = require('async-foreach').forEach;
var bulk = Things.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();


  Things.find({}).lean().execAsync(execSettings).then(function(resp){

    forEach(resp, function(template, index, arr) {

      var done = this.async();

      bulk.find({'_id': template._id}).update({$set: {_sid: generateShortId()}});
      bulk.execute(function (error) {
           done();                  
      });

    }, function(notAborted, arr){

        res.json({done: true, arr: arr.length});

    });

  });
```